# Is there a less cumbersome method of retrieving getter and setter methods that are somewhere in the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, prototypal-inheritance

I have a reference to an object, which has a getter and setter for a certain property somewhere in its prototype chain. I want to get a reference to the getter and setter methods, and the object they're on. I know I can do it by manually iterating over every prototype object and checking `hasOwnProperty`, as in the following snippet:

```js
const obj2 = (() => {
  const baseProto = {
    get prop() {
      return 'propval';
    },
    set prop(newVal) {
      console.log('setting...');
    }
  };
  const obj1 = Object.create(baseProto);
  return Object.create(obj1);
})();

// From having a reference to obj2, want to get the getter or setter methods,
// and want to get the object they're on, without invoking them:

let currentObj = obj2;
const propToFind = 'prop';
let get, set, foundProto;
while (currentObj) {
  if (currentObj.hasOwnProperty(propToFind)) {
    foundProto = currentObj;
    ({ get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(currentObj, propToFind));
    break;
  }
  currentObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentObj);
}
if (foundProto) {
  console.log('Found:', get, set, foundProto);
}
```

This seems rather cumbersome, and `while` loops are *ugly*. Of course, the getter and setter can be *invoked*, with the calling context of the current object, with very simple code like

```
obj2.prop = 'newVal';   // invoke setter
const val = obj2.prop;  // invoke getter
```

But that invokes the functions without being able to interact with them (or the prototype object they're on).

Is there any clearer, shorter way of achieving what I'm doing in the snippet above?

Comment: "*without being able to interact with them (or the prototype object they're on).*" - what are you trying to do? Normally you never need to access the functions directly, that's why there is no extra syntax to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

> This seems rather cumbersome, and `while` loops are *ugly*

I don't think this is cumbersome, it's just what you have to do when trying to find a property anywhere on the prototype chain.

You don't have to write a `while` loop of course, the iteration can be easily expressed as a `for` loop:

```
let get, set, foundProto;
for (let currentObj = obj2; currentObj; currentObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentObj)) {
  if (currentObj.hasOwnProperty('prop')) {
    foundProto = currentObj;
    ({ get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(currentObj, 'prop'));
    break;
  }
}
if (foundProto) {
  console.log('Found:', get, set, foundProto);
}
```

You can of course also write a helper function to do this, like

```
function getInheritedPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop) {
  for (; obj != null; obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
      return { foundProto: obj, ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop) };
    }
  }
  return null;
}
var result = getInheritedPropertyDescriptor(obj2, 'prop');
if (result) {
  console.log('Found:', result.get, result.set, result.foundProto);
}
```